# Mongodb aggregation cursor throws error using cloned cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor, aggregation

i have an aggregation cursor which i need to clone, so:

```
const aggCursorCloned = aggCursor.clone()
const aggArray = aggCursorCloned.toArray()
```

but throws: `no such command: 'lsid'`

tried to find anything related with lsid and mongo driver and only find somethin with conection. My connection method:

```
...
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
...
```

**Note: if i use cursor not cloned (original cursor), works fine**

i'm using nodejs 12 and mongodb driver 3.5.3

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: There's an open issue -> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2144

Comment: @eol thanks i'll be watching the issue and comment here when they answer